# bridge between UDP and serial doesn't work

Tags: serial-port, udp, socat

I've created a bridge between UDP and serial port using `socat`. Here is what I have

```
socat -xv udp4:localhost:54321    open:/dev/ttyUSB1,rawer,lockfile=/tmp/s1.locak,echo=1,b115200,crnl
```

To monitor data I run

```
tcpdump -i any -vnn port 54321
```

To send data I run

```
echo -n "hello world" | nc -4u -w1 localhost 54321
```

I do see data going into UDP but I don't see anything coming out of serial. Shouldn't `socat` options `-x` and `-v` display the data? If I understand it correctly, `socat` doesn't display any data because there is not data flowing from UDP to serial.

Just to make sure that I'm not missing anything, I actually connected an oscilloscope to the serial lines to monitor the data physically. But I didn't see anything.

Has anyone had any experience bridging UDP and serial? I would really appreciate any help with this. Maybe there is another way of doing what I'm doing? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is what I want to do

```
Device        |     Serial       |      PC
              |------------------|    
Map Network to|                  | Map network to Serialport
   Serial Port|                  |  SerialPort
              |                  |
    SerialPort|                  |
```

Comment: Related - this shows a TCP to serial connector - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624653/create-a-virtual-serial-port-connection-over-tcp. I'd start with this and confirm that it works, and then mix in the UDP.

Comment: Another related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207980/bridge-serial-ports-over-network.

Comment: It looks like `udp4:` is for sending out data over UDP. Since you want `socat`to listen for incoming UDP packets, perhaps replace `udp4:` with `udp4-listen:`.

Comment: @slm I have a different structure. Will edit the post to show what I mean